# Entity Framework: Is there a method to compare for equal values of EntityObject?

Tags: entity-framework, equality

Is there a simple way to compare two EntityObjects for value-equality.
I simply want to check if all the database-values are the same, so I don't care if the EntityKey is different.

Is this possible built-in? Or should I just write my own method.

I guess Equals() doesn't work as I want it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Equals()` [checks for referential equality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx), so it wouldn't help you there.

Take a look at this question: [What is the best way to compare two entity framework entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092534/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-two-entity-framework-entities)

UPDATE 2014:
A more complete answer, in line with the current state of EF, would be that you could override the Equality operator in a code-first model to provide a check for value-equality.

Comment: And what if I implement IEquality<TEntity>?

Comment: I'm confused, you say: `Equals() checks for referential equality`, but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) says `To check for value equality, use Equals or Equals.`

Comment: @TheRedPea - The default implementation of Equals() checks for referential equality: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx.  If you do not override Equals() it is equivalent to ReferenceEquals().  You can, however, override Equals() and provide a custom implementation that could check for value equality.  You'd want to take care in documenting this behavior, as this might be counter to what consumers of your API would expect.