# Entity Framework DBSet Any() Not Working As Expected

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I’m trying to add an AddRangeUnique extension method on DBSet in order to easily add only unique values but I’m seeing some behavior I suspect is a bug, but seeing as my c# experience is limited I wanted to ask here first in case I’m just misunderstanding something.

I took the relevant snippet from the code where I added 2 variables to demonstrate the problem.

```
public static void AddRangeUnique<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> source, IEnumerable<TEntity> other)
    where TEntity : class
{
    // contains 1 item (incorrect)
    var s1 = other.Where(x => !source.Any(y => y.Equals(x))).ToList();
    // contains 0 items (correct - expected as the item in other matches a value in source)
    var s2 = other.Where(x => !source.ToList().Any(y => y.Equals(x))).ToList();
}
```

My question is why does the linq query provide different results when I use source or source.ToList() in the where clause. I would expect it to be the same?

Thanks for any help/guidance.

Comment: Can you provide the test data you are sending the method?

Comment: It is `Equals`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785405/1260204 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1092534/1260204

Comment: Every `source.ToList()` call brings the whole database table in memory. In your case, it does that **for each** element in `other`. Shortly, never do `ToList` on `DbSet`. I don't think such extension method can be implemented generically w/o having some associated metadata and/or arguments specifying which properties define the uniqueness. Looks like you rely on `Equals` override, but it doesn't play when the query is translated and executed as SQL. I'm even surprised that EF allowed you to use `Equals` in the first query - are you using EF Core?