# Entity Framework not comparing same objects returned at different times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to be able to return a list of Vehicle objects that are free to be booked between specific dates.

I have a method that returns a list of the Bookings that are currently in the database between those days and each booking has a related vehicle object, so I know all the vehicles that are unavailable.

I have another method that returns a list of all Vehicles in the database but I need a way of comparing the Booking.Vehicle with the Vehicle objects returned from the list.

I tried this

```
foreach(var booking in bookings)
{
    allVehicles.Remove(booking.Vehicle)
}
```

But the vehicle wouldn't remove, why are the objects not being compared correctly? Even though its the same vehicle object being removed.

```
//Testing to see if the objects compare as expected (they don't)
public static List<Vehicle> AvaliableVehiclesBetween(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
{

    List<Booking> bookings = Booking.BookingsBetween(StartDate, EndDate);
    List<Vehicle> vehicles = AllVehicles();
    Vehicle v = vehicles[0];
    if(bookings[0].Vehicle.Equals(v)) {
        vehicles = null;
    }

    return vehicles;
}
```

after I run this the vehicles doesn't equal null;
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using just the primary key ~ID for your matching

```
var bookedIDs = bookings.Select(b => b.Vehicle.ID).ToList();
var freeVehicles = allVehicles.Where(v => !bookedIDs.Contains(v.ID));
```

As for your actual question, you probably don't have a Comparator setup for your objects, so it's comparing by memory location/reference. [What is the best way to compare two entity framework entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092534/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-two-entity-framework-entities)

Comment: I think your code is comparing the booking ID's to the vehicle ID's, which would yield incorrect results.

Comment: One more catch -- since the `bookedIDs` will not be used for collection manipulation (`.Add`, `.Remove`, etc), use `.ToArray()` instead of `.ToList()`. You can even omit it altogether if `.Contains(v.ID)` will be the only place where it is used, because it will automatically be enumerated in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things.
1) If you need to compare the whole object, then you need to serialize both of the objects into any format(XML), and then compare it.Because objects contains some metadata, which may not be equals.

2) you can compare any of property of both objects like "VehicleId".

```
public static List<Vehicle> AvaliableVehiclesBetween(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
```

{

```
List<Booking> bookings = Booking.BookingsBetween(StartDate, EndDate);
List<Vehicle> vehicles = AllVehicles();
Vehicle v = vehicles[0];
if(bookings[0]!=null && v!=null)
{
  if(bookings[0].Vehicle.VehicleId.Equals(v.VehicleId)) 
  {
    vehicles = null;
  }
}
return vehicles;
```

}