# Is there a shortcut to compare multiple properties in c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have to check if an objects properties have changed, but only a selection of it's properties not all. Like id, creation_date, ... don't have to be checked

I wonder if there is any short variant to write this, which I don't know

For now I do a simple compare of each property:

```
if (user.first_name != uFirstName || user.last_name != uLastName
    || user.street != uStreet || user.zip_code != uZipCode
    || user.city != uCity || user.country_id != countryAX.id
    || user.email != uEMail || user.phone != uPhone)
    {
        ...
    }
```

"user" is an EntityFramework object

Comment: An `Equals` method? It still would do the same generally, but then you can reuse it.

Comment: You could see your question as duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1092534/993547), which asks how to compare two EF entities.

Comment: EF translates expressions to SQL. There is no way to compare multiple fields at the same time in SQL. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? Does it have to do with concurrency? Eg. EF itself will check for changes to properties or any rowversion field to ensure an object hasn't changed. Or are you trying to avoid saving newly attached objects if they haven't changed?

Comment: If you want to perform optimistic concurrency based on the values of a few properties only, you can add the [ConcurrencyCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.concurrencycheckattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)  attribute to the properties. In fact, you'd have to add the attribute to *all* properties if you wanted all of them to participate in the concurrency check

Comment: The problem is already solved, with my script => Check if I need to update my DataRow; I mainly thought, maybe there is a cool shorthand to write this

Comment: @Patrick: I don't have two Entity-Objects

Answer (score 1):

I would override `Equals` (+`GetHashCode`) in your `User`-class. Then create a second instance from those variables if you don't already have one and you can write: `if(user1Info.Equals(user2Info)){...}`. If you don't use code-first and your entity is autogenerated you can create a `partical class User` to implement `Equals`.

```
public partial class User
{
    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        // implement according to your specifications
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() 
    {
        // implement according to your specifications
    }
}
```

Another option is to use an anonymous type which automatically overrides `Equals` + `GetHashCode`:

```
var user1Info = new 
{ 
    user.first_name,
    user.last_name,
    user.street, // ...
};
var user2Info = new 
{ 
    first_name = uFirstName,
    last_name = uLastName,
    street = uStreet, // ...
};
if(user1Info.Equals(user2Info))
{

}
```

Comment: Yes, this would be obvious for me, but I don't have two Entity-Objects, but one Entity-Object and many single properties whoch don't represent the full Entity-Object

Answer (score 0):

Trying something like this

```
public static bool PublicInstancePropertiesEqual<T>(T value, T tobecompared) where T : class 
  {
     if (value!= null && tobecompared!= null)
     {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
              object selfValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(self, null);//Get Current value
              object toValue = getCompareToValue();

              if (selfValue != toValue && (selfValue == null || !selfValue.Equals(toValue)))
              {
                 return false;
              }
        }
        return true;
     }
     return value == tobecompared;
  }
```

Comment: The OP wants to use a *subset* of properties, not all of them.

Comment: Correct, I cannot create a second object, because this would always be different, hence I cannot reproduce for exampe the creation date